# MEMCACHED get method always returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, memcached

I'm trying to implement caching in our application using Memcached, I was able to set the key and value to the server, but when I'm trying to get the value it always return a null. Below is my sample code snippet.

```
//memcached configuration in my web config
<enyim.com>
  <memcached protocol="Binary">
    <servers>
      <add address="127.0.0.1" port="11211"/>
    </servers>
   <socketPool minPoolSize="10" maxPoolSize="100" 
                  connectionTimeout="00:10:00" deadTimeout="00:05:00"/>

  </memcached>
</enyim.com>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="enyim.com">
        <section name="memcached"
           type="Enyim.Caching.Configuration.MemcachedClientSection,
           Enyim.Caching"/>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>





 //Get method in my controller
 public object GetSalesOrder()
 {
      using (Enyim.Caching.MemcachedClient mc = new Enyim.Caching.MemcachedClient())
      {
          mc.FlushAll();
          var salesOrders = salesOrderListService.GetSalesOrders();
          byte[] val;
          val = S.Serializer.objectToByteArray(salesOrders);
          mc.Store(Enyim.Caching.Memcached.StoreMode.Set, "salesOrderList", val);
          byte[] data = mc.Get<byte[]>("salesOrderList");
          var returnObj = S.Serializer.ByteArrayToObject<List<Model.SalesOrderList>>((byte[])val);

          return returnObj;
       }            
  }


//Model

[Serializable]
[ResourceType("SalesOrderList")]
public class SalesOrderList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code{ get; set; }
    public string CustomerName{ get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShipDate { get; set; }
}

//Serializer class
public class Serializer
    {
        public static byte[] objectToByteArray<T>(T obj)
        {
            System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

            using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public static Object ByteArrayToObject<T>(byte[] arrBytes)
        {
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
                ms.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
                ms.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

                object obj = (Object)formatter.Deserialize(ms);

                return obj;
            }
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I see wrong in your code is that you don't have a cache key to store or to retrieve your data from. The way I'm doing it in my code is as follow:

```
// create cachekey for storing and retrieving
var cacheKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
// store for an hour
// memcachedClient.Store( StoreMode.Set, SanitizeCacheKey( cacheKey ), value, validFor )
mc.Store(StoreMode.Set, cacheKey , val, new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0));

AccessCache.Get<byte[]>( cacheKey )
```